# Delete the ith element of a list

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

Write a function that deletes the *i*th element of a list. If the length of the list is less than *i*, return the list.

This is the output wanted:

```
- deleteIth([1,2,3,4,5,6],3);
val it = [1,2,4,5,6] : int list

- deleteIth([1,2,3,4,5,6],7);
val it = [1,2,3,4,5,6] : int list
```

Here's my code:

```
fun deleteIth (L, i) =
    let
        (* Deletes the element of a list at ith index *)
        fun delete (nil, i, position) = nil
        | delete (x::xs, i, position) = if i = position then xs else 

x :: delete (xs, i, position + 1)
        in
            if i >= 0 andalso i < length L then delete (L, i, 0) else L
        end;
```

note: the line x :: delete (xs, I, position + 1) should be right after the else in the previous line the line wrap made me show the code this way. Sorry for that.

But my code out puts

```
 - deleteIth([1,2,3,4,5,6],3);
    val it = [1,2,3,5,6] : int list

 - deleteIth([1,2,3,4,5,6],7);
    val it = [1,2,3,4,5,6] : int list
```

I would appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: You don't need the helper function or `length`. The list and the index are all the parameters you need. (Hint: count down instead of up.)

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to get the output I wanted. But how would I go about doing it without the helper function.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got your expected results, here's a shorter version that only traverses the list once, and never beyond the element to remove.
(`length` must traverse the entire list to determine its length. It's possibly the least useful list function.)

The general case, k > 1 and the list is not empty:

- To remove the k:th element, remove element k-1 from the tail of the list, then add the head of the original list to the result.

Base cases:

- Removing element 1 from a list produces the tail of the list.
- Removing anything from the empty list produces the empty list.

The case where the list is shorter than k will terminate when it reaches the empty list.

Like this:

```
fun delete_ith ([], k) = []
  | delete_ith (x::xs, 1) = xs
  | delete_ith (x::xs, k) = x :: delete_ith (xs, k - 1)
```